# Dual geometric graph of a planar graph

Tags: planar-graphs, geometric-graph

Does the dual geometric graph of a planar graph have a planar embedding?
 Aplanar graph is a graph that can be embedded in the plane such that any edges can cross each other at their end points only
Dual graph is generated from a planar graph by representing each face as a vertic
And connecting two vertices by an edge if there is a boundery edge between the faces represented by the vertices

Comment: "the dual graph of a planar graph is planar" hence the answer is yes

Comment: Dual graph includes the outer region of the original graph as a vertice

Comment: What is the proof of that?

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/606384/565609) is one @אמנון ברטור

Comment: Hi אמנון ברטור, did you see that your question has been answered? Please mark it "accepted" if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "yes": a graph is planar if and only if its dual is also planar.

The proof outline is as follows:

1. A graph can be drawn without crossing edges on the plane (i.e., is planar) if and only if it can be drawn without crossing edges on the sphere.
2. Given a spherical embedding of a planar graph without crossings, you can trivially construct a spherical embedding of its dual without crossings by connecting the centres of adjacent faces with straight lines. That gives you a non-crossing spherical embedding of the dual, proving that the dual is planar.

If you also want a proof-sketch for (1), let me know. The construction is similarly easy.